Como puedo hacer que un TextInput en Kivy el texto se vea como un *?
Tengo un TextInput en mi ventana de Kivy y quiero que al yo ingresar los datos estos se vean como un *, kivy no tendra alguna propiedad para el elemento TextInput asi como tiene para centrar el texto que se ingresa?
Código:

TextInput:
    id: contraseña
    hint_text: "Contraseña"
    hint_text_color: (0.071, 0.416, 0.427)
    foreground_color: (0.071, 0.416, 0.427)
    background_color: (0.8314, 0.9098, 0.9098)
    pos: 135, 280
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 130
    height: 40
    halign: "center"
    font_name: "MulledWineSeason.otf"
    font_size: 20



Coloca password: True y si quieres cambiar el * por algun otro caracter añade password_mask: -

**Muchas gracias, me ha solucionado el problema **

Establece la propiedad password a True

password
If True, the widget will display its characters as the character set in password_mask.


Si True, el widget mostrará sus caracteres como el carácter establecido en password_mask.

Y, cómo se ve, la propiedad relacionada password_mask te sirve para definir el carácter que seerá visible dentro del edit:

password_mask
Sets the character used to mask the text when password is True. ... password_mask is a StringProperty and defaults to '*'.


Establece el carácter que se usa para enmascarar el texto cuándo password es True. ... password_mask es una StringProperty y su valor por defecto es '*'.

